# Why am I getting 'Error: $injector:modulerr Module Error' in this basic Controller?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-controller

Using [AngularJS 1.3.15](https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.3.15/angular.min.js)

**jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/leongaban/2g8vwmzo/**

> Failed to instantiate module myApp due to:
>   Error: [$injector:nomod] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.3.15/$injector/nomod?p0=myApp
>       at Error (native)
>       at https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.3.15/angular.min.js:6:417
>       at

```
(function() {
'use strict';
var app = angular
    .module('myApp', ['MyCtrl'])
    .controller('MyCtrl', Controller);
Controller.$inject = ['$scope'];

function Controller($scope) {
    var vm = this;
    var vs = $scope;

    activate();

    ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

    function activate() {
        vs.name = "stackoverflow";

        vs.fonts = [
            {title: "Arial" , text: 'Arial rules!' },
            {title: "Helvetica" , text: 'Helvetica is hot!' }
        ];

        vs.change= function(option){
            alert(option.title);
        }
    }
}
})();
```

Markup:

```
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="MyCtrl">

    <h1>{{name}}</h1>

    <select ng-model="opt"
            ng-change="change(font)">

        <option ng-repeat="font in fonts" value="{{font.title}}">
            {{font.title}}
        </option>

    </select>

    <p>{{opt}}</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Maybe because you're firing `activate()` before its defined

Comment: No the function would be hoisted up to the top in this case anyways, but also tried it without the activate function and still running into that `$injector:modulerr`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change this

`.module('myApp', ['MyCtrl'])`

to

`.module('myApp', [])`

and you are good to go!

The second parameter in module function is an array of module dependencies, which are other modules that `myApp` module is dependent upon. `MyCtrl` is a controller not module.

**Update**: Change the fiddle settings. Set second dropdown to `no wrap in body`

See it running here http://jsfiddle.net/0h4cs2tp/

Comment: Hmm, just tried it http://jsfiddle.net/leongaban/2g8vwmzo/12/ still getting that error :(

Comment: There was one more problem.

Comment: To expand on the `no wrap` issue. You are running your code in `onload`, so your `myApp` module will be defined _after_ Angular bootstraps your application. i.e. tries to use it. You generally should either just put the code in a script tag, not in any page events, to avoid this. If you _do_ need to run it later, then remove the `ng-app` attribute and [bootstrap it manually](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/bootstrap)